# Material-UI How to change TransitionComponent of Customized Snackbar to Slide

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, slide, snackbar

I want to change the transition of snackbar to Slide Up instead of Grow (the default behaviour), but I found it difficult to do so on Customized snackbar:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CheckCircleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CheckCircle';
import ErrorIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Error';
import InfoIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Info';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import green from '@material-ui/core/colors/green';
import amber from '@material-ui/core/colors/amber';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Snackbar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar';
import SnackbarContent from '@material-ui/core/SnackbarContent';
import WarningIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Warning';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const variantIcon = {
  success: CheckCircleIcon,
  warning: WarningIcon,
  error: ErrorIcon,
  info: InfoIcon,
};

const useStyles1 = makeStyles(theme => ({
  success: {
    backgroundColor: green[600],
  },
  error: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.error.dark,
  },
  info: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark,
  },
  warning: {
    backgroundColor: amber[700],
  },
  icon: {
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  iconVariant: {
    opacity: 0.9,
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  message: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
}));

function MySnackbarContentWrapper(props) {
  const classes = useStyles1();
  const { className, message, onClose, variant, ...other } = props;
  const Icon = variantIcon[variant];

  return (
    <SnackbarContent
      className={clsx(classes[variant], className)}
      aria-describedby="client-snackbar"
      message={
        <span id="client-snackbar" className={classes.message}>
          <Icon className={clsx(classes.icon, classes.iconVariant)} />
          {message}
        </span>
      }
      action={[
        <IconButton key="close" aria-label="Close" color="inherit" onClick={onClose}>
          <CloseIcon className={classes.icon} />
        </IconButton>,
      ]}
      {...other}
    />
  );
}

MySnackbarContentWrapper.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string,
  message: PropTypes.node,
  onClose: PropTypes.func,
  variant: PropTypes.oneOf(['success', 'warning', 'error', 'info']).isRequired,
};

const useStyles2 = makeStyles(theme => ({
  margin: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}));

function CustomizedSnackbars() {
  const classes = useStyles2();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  function handleClick() {
    setOpen(true);
  }

  function handleClose(event, reason) {
    if (reason === 'clickaway') {
      return;
    }

    setOpen(false);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" className={classes.margin} onClick={handleClick}>
        Open success snackbar
      </Button>
      <Snackbar
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'bottom',
          horizontal: 'left',
        }}
        open={open}
        autoHideDuration={6000}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MySnackbarContentWrapper
          onClose={handleClose}
          variant="success"
          message="This is a success message!"
        />
      </Snackbar>
      <MySnackbarContentWrapper
        variant="error"
        className={classes.margin}
        message="This is an error message!"
      />
      <MySnackbarContentWrapper
        variant="warning"
        className={classes.margin}
        message="This is a warning message!"
      />
      <MySnackbarContentWrapper
        variant="info"
        className={classes.margin}
        message="This is an information message!"
      />
      <MySnackbarContentWrapper
        variant="success"
        className={classes.margin}
        message="This is a success message!"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default CustomizedSnackbars;
```

Here is what I have done so far:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-2dvos

The error message is what I have got so far.

Help please, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is in the way you are using the `Slide` component.

https://material-ui.com/api/slide/

`children   element     A single child content element.
⚠️ Needs to be able to hold a ref.`

The children to the Slide element is your `MySnackbarContentWrapper` component, which is not taking or holding a ref.  Update this to hold a ref and it works as expected:

```
const MySnackbarContentWrapper = React.forwardRef((props, ref) =>  {
  const classes = useStyles1();
  const { className, message, onClose, variant, ...other } = props;
  const Icon = variantIcon[variant];

  return (
    <SnackbarContent
      ref={ref}
      className={clsx(classes[variant], className)}
      aria-describedby="client-snackbar"
      message={
        <span id="client-snackbar" className={classes.message}>
          <Icon className={clsx(classes.icon, classes.iconVariant)} />
          {message}
        </span>
      }
      action={[
        <IconButton
          key="close"
          aria-label="Close"
          color="inherit"
          onClick={onClose}
        >
          <CloseIcon className={classes.icon} />
        </IconButton>
      ]}
      {...other}
    />
  );
})
```